# Организация мультиязычного приложения (php, yii2 framework)

Tags: php, yii2

столкнулся с проблемой организации мультиязычного приложения на php, mysql, yii2.

В ходе "гугления", анализа найденных подходов и решений, вывел наиболее для себя подходящие, но все же сомневаюсь в их универсальности.

Допустим у нас есть сущность News, и она имеет следующую структуру:

**News**

id primary

title string(255)

text longtext

**Вариант 1** Создание дубликата таблицы, с префиксом кода языка.

**News_en**

id primary

title string(255)

text longtext

Смущает количество таких таблиц, при большом количестве языков в приложении.

**Вариант 2** Создание одной мультиязычной таблицы

**News_lang**

id
news_id
text
title
lang_id

Смущает наличие связей, а как следствие более сложных запросов в выборке.

**Вариант 3** Создание одной единственной таблицы для всех мультиязычных сущностей.

**multilanguages**

id
property
langId
Value

Смущает сложность выборки, к примеру в поиске по контенту.

**Вариант 4** Хранение в JSON.
В случае если необходимо таблицу сделать мультиязычной, для каждого атрибута сущности предполагаю следующую структуру:

**news**

id
title longtext() => {'ru'='title', 'en'='title'}
text longtext() => {'ru'='text', 'en'='text'}

Смущает ограничение MYSQL longtext, а также костыли с выборкой, поиском, записи данных.

Прощу подтолкнуть на правильную мысль )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1 можно выкинуть сразу. Вариант 3 слишком усложняет жизнь.

Вариант 2 является классическим для реляционной модели. Сложность запросов не беда. Они пишутся один раз. И если запрос составлен правильно и правильно сделана БД (структура, индексы), проблем быть не должно.

Вариант 4 очень плохо ложится на реляционную модель. Здесь проще использовать документоориентированные NoSQL решения. Такие как MongoDB например. Но, если всё правильно сделать быстродействие может оказаться гораздо выше чем с MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам посоветовал другой способ, сам недавно реализовывал:
1. Мультиязычность самого приложения реализовал при помощи klisl/yii2-languages
2. Мультиязычность в БД сделана следующим образом:

На примере NEWS. Есть две таблицы `news` и `news_content`, в таблице `news` мы храним не мультиязычные поля, а именно `id`,`code`,`date`,`image`,`likes` в таблице `news_content` у нас следующие столбцы `id`,`news_id`,`title`,`description`,`body`,`lang`

А дальше, в модели News мы создаём реляцию

```
public function getNewscontent(){
        return $this->hasOne(NewsContent::className(), ['news_id' => 'id'])->where(['lang' => Yii::$app->language]);
    }
```

И получается следующая выборка `$model = News::find()->joinWith('newscontent')->where(['news.code' => $code])->asArray()->one();` нам выдаст новость на текущем языке, или же вот все новости на текущем языке `$model = News::find()->joinWith('newscontent')->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])->asArray()->all();`

Почему я выбрал этот способ? Удобно разрабатывать админ панель, организовывать заполнение мультиязычных полей. Как это делать?

В модели `News` создаём `public $contents;`.

Далее в `admin/views/news/_form.php` добавляем такой кусочек кода:

```
<? $langs = \Yii::$app->getModule('languages')->languages; ?>

    <div class="tabs-contents">
        <div class="langs">
            <span data-lang="all">ALL</span>
            <?
            foreach ($langs as $title_lang => $key){
                ?>
                <span data-lang="<?=$key?>" <?if($key == Yii::$app->language) echo 'class="current"'?>><?=$key?></span>
                <?
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?
            foreach ($langs as $title_lang => $key){
                echo '<div class="tab-content '.$key.'">';
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][title]')->textInput()->label('Название новости (' . $key . ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][description]')->textInput()->label('Описание (' . $key . ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][body]')->textInput()->label('Текст новости (' . $key. ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][location]')->textInput()->label('Локация (' . $key. ')');
                    echo $form->field($model, 'contents['.$key.'][id]')->hiddenInput()->label(false);
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Т.е. генерируем мультиязычные поля, у меня к примеру 4 языка (на самом деле в такой структуре неважно сколько языков).

В контроллерах дальше просто отлавливаем мультиязычные фрагменты, пример `create`:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new News();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            //Изображение
            $imageName = time();
            $model->image_container = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_container');
            if(!empty($model->image_container)){
                $model->image_container->saveAs('uploads/news/list_images/article_'.$imageName.'.'.$model->image_container->extension);
                $model->image = '/uploads/news/list_images/article_'.$imageName.'.'.$model->image_container->extension;
            }
            //Изображение
            if(!$model->save()) return;

            //Сохранение мультиязычных полей
            $NewsContents = Yii::$app->request->post()["News"]["contents"];
            foreach ($NewsContents as $lang => $content){
                $NewsContent = new NewsContent();
                $NewsContent->load(["NewsContent" => $content]);
                $NewsContent->lang = $lang;
                $NewsContent->news_id = $model->id;
                $NewsContent->save();
            }
            //Сохранение мультиязычных полей

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
```

`update` делаем по аналогу, и `delete`:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        //Удаление контента вместе с новостью
        NewsContent::deleteAll(['news_id' => $id]);

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю за информацию :)